# Generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{F_{2k}F_{n-k}}{10^n}, $$

where $F_n$ - $n-th$ Fibonacci number

Any hint how to start with this?

I have thought about convolution of two Fibonacci sequences, but there is $F_{2k}$, instead of $F_{k}$.

Comment: Then use $\sum F_{2k}x^k$ instead of $\sum F_{k}x^k$ as one of the factors ...

Comment: I still do not understand how to use it. If I would have there $F_k F_{n-k}$, I could use $F(z)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} F_k x^k \right) \cdot \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} F_{2k} x^k \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} C_n x^n$$
Now $C_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n F_{2k} F_{n-k}$. We now have that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} F_k x^k & = \dfrac{x}{1-x-x^2}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} F_{2k} x^k & = \dfrac1{\phi-\psi} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi^{2k} x^k - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \psi^{2k} x^k\right) = \dfrac1{\phi - \psi}\left(\dfrac1{1-\phi^2x} - \dfrac1{1-\psi^2x}\right)\\
& = \dfrac{(\phi + \psi)x}{1-(\phi^2+\psi^2)x + \phi^2 \psi^2 x^2} = \dfrac{x}{1-3x+x^2}
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} C_n x^n = \dfrac{x}{1-x-x^2} \cdot \dfrac{x}{1-3x+x^2}$$
Now plug in $x=\dfrac1{10}$ and get the answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!! One more question: the result (after substitution $x=1/10$) can be interpreted somehow?

Comment: @JosephConrad I do not follow your question. For instance, if you want $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{C_n}{5^n}$, we can plug in $x=1/5$ on the right hand side to get the answer.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What is the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in $(F(x)+F(-x))\cdot F(x^2)$?